# Java Webstart not loading Jetty HTTP server resource

Tags: java, resources, jetty, loading, java-web-start

I have created an application, which uses the Jetty HTTP server jar files:

jetty-all-9.3.7.v20160115-uber.jar and
jetty-http-spi-9.3.7.v20160115.jar.

I have added the following Class Path definition to the Manifest file:

Class-Path: lib/jetty-all-9.3.7.v20160115-uber.jar lib/jetty-http-sp
 i-9.3.7.v20160115.jar ...

When running the application using : java -jar  it works fine.
When running the application using webstart, the two resources I mentioned above, are not loaded. Every other resources mentioned in the .jnlp file are loaded.

I have coded a dump of the classpath, when the aplication is running and here I see, that the two .jar files are mentioned correctly.

In which areas should I be looking to solve this issue ? Could this be un-matched Java version ? Or are there other reasons that may cause resources not being loaded by Java Webstart ?

```
<jnlp xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" spec="1.0+"
  codebase="http://www.smartbusinessexplorer.dk/SmartBusinessExplorer/"
  href="SmartBusinessExplorer_x64_commIT400.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>SmartBusinessExplorer for commIT400</title>
    <vendor>SmartBusinessSoftware</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.smartbusinessexplorer.dk"/>
    <description>Explore business data the smart way.</description>
    <description kind="short">Explore business data the smart way.</description>
    <description kind="tooltip">SmartBusinessExplorer</description>
    <icon kind="default" href="images/applicationIcon-32.png" width="16" height="16"/>
    <icon kind="shortcut" href="images/applicationIcon-32.png" width="32" height="32"/>
    <icon kind="splash" href="images/splash-screen.png"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
    <shortcut online="true" install="true">
        <desktop/>
        <menu submenu="SmartBusinessSoftware"/>
    </shortcut>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.8.0_74+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="8192m" java-vm-args="-verbose"/>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.1+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
    <jar href="SmartBusinessExplorer_x64_commIT400.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="plugins/commIT400Connector.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-common.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-grids.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jide-pivot.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jt400.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jetty-all-9.3.7.v20160115-uber.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jetty-http-spi-9.3.7.v20160115.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/task-dialog-1.3.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="lib/x64/sqljdbc_auth.jar"/>
    <property name="application.propertiesFile" value="properties_commIT400.xml"/>
    <property name="application.title" value="{application.getTextConstantById(&quot;CommIT400Connector.application.Title.Commit&quot;).getText()}"/>
    <property name="CommitConnector.navigatorFile" value="http://www.smartbusinessexplorer.dk/SmartBusinessExplorer/plugins/CommitConnector-Navigator.xml"/>
</resources>
<application-desc name="SmartBusinessExplorer" main-class="com.smartbusinesssoftware.smartbusinessexplorer.SmartBusinessExplorerApplication"/>
<update check="always" policy="always"/>
```

UPDATE :

I had a look at the MANIFEST.MF file in one of the jar files and I found out, that this jar file is actually an OSGI bundle. So I am thinking, that maybe my prolem is, that the jar file is not loaded, because I need to load it differently ?
This may change my question to How to load an OSGI bundle in a Java Webstart application ?

UPDATE 2:

I have now further investigated this isse and it look to me, that there is an error in the com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider class in the loadProviderFromProperty method: It uses the system classloader when loading the class and the system class loader is not aware of the resources added by the JNLP file.

I wonder how I can fix this ...

Comment: Please post the content of your JNLP file

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for commenting. I have added the contents of my JNLP file.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Andrew, I believe the JNLP file is ok. When I eg. delete the resources I mentioned in the Java Console Panel, they are immediateliy added in the resources, when I start the application. And if I delete the files at the source, I do get a Missing File error.